# Making cylinders in python?

Tags: python, vpython

I am trying to make a cylinder in Python 3.3.2 using the following code:

```
rod = cylinder(pos=(0,2,1), axis=(5,0,0), radius=1)
rod.pos = (15,11,9) # change (x,y,z)
rod.x = 15 # only change pos.x
rod.color = (0,0,1) # make rod be blue
rod.red = 0.4
```

With help from this site: http://www.vpython.org/contents/docs_vp5/visual/cylinder.html

The output is: NameError: name 'cylinder' is not defined

Is there anything I need to install or must I import something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you're missing an import statement.  Are you not importing any modules? Or did you just leave out that code?

Comment: No, I don't know what to import - if i do what martijn pieters said, it outputs ImportError: No module named 'visual'

Comment: Does VPython work with Python3? I thought VPython was for Python2 not Python3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import `cylinder` from the `visual` module before you can use it in your module:

```
from visual import cylinder
```

The [`vpython` tutorial](http://www.vpython.org/contents/docs_vp5/visual/VPython_Intro.pdf) imports *everything* in one go from that module with the syntax:

```
from visual import *
```

This all assumes you are using the VPython IDE, downloaded from the [project website](http://vpython.org/).

Comment: It says: ImportError: No module named 'visual'

Comment: @TimTimmy: Did you *install* `vpython` at all?

Comment: Yes, I installed Python 3.3.2 on my computer. Must i say a statement at the beginning of the code about vpython?

Comment: @TimTimmy: What platform are you on? Did you follow the download instructions for your platform?

Comment: @TimTimmy: I see at the bottom of the Windows and Mac download pages that the current version does *not* work with Python 3.x. See http://www.vpython.org/contents/download_windows.html

Comment: Is there any other way to make cylinder in python without installing anything?

Comment: @TimTimmy: no, not without a lot of coding. The standard Python library does not include a 3D framework.

Comment: @TimTimmy:  What is your goal?  Is it to learn programming?  Is it to do 3d modeling?  Is it to see a 3d cylinder on your screen?

Comment: I am using this to make a program in Python that outputs the volume and surface area of a cylinder. Could I make it put a picture of a cylinder and make it enlarge to the input of cm you enter?

Comment: @TimTimmy: sure, but it won't necessarily be easy. What GUI are you planning to use? How much do you know about graphic user interface programming to start with? Etc.

Comment: I actually don't know anything about GUI in Python. I've only done 50% in codecademy for Python.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski I'm trying to make it 3D.

Comment: Does VPython work with Python3? I thought VPython was for Python2 not Python3.

Comment: @Devyn: it doesn't; that was one if the problems.